# “keytool” no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable en expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy desarrollando con *Expo* en *React Native* y quiero ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
expo fetch:android:hashes
```

Al hacerlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> "Are you sure you have keytool installed?
> keytool is a part of OpenJDK: https://openjdk.java.net/
> Also make sure that keytool is in your PATH after installation.
> "keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> spawn keytool ENOENT
> Error: spawn keytool ENOENT
> at notFoundError (C:\Users\54113\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
> at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\54113\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\54113\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)

Comment: Pues eso, que no tienes el openjdk instalado o no tienes el path de java puesto correctamente

Comment: sisi, lo tengo instalado, me dice que le coloque la ruta de donde esta... y lo hice, pero no me lo toma